# Feedback on the new ask question page - Formatting suggestions

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, editor, formatting, ask-question-form

I think you guys did a great job with the re-design of the ask question page. However there is this bit that I find can be improved.

There are currently three (or even 4) ways to format code:

- Indenting by 4 spaces (or selecting the code and either pressing ctrl + k or clicking the code button in the editor).
- Creating a code fence with three backticks ( ``` )
- Creating a code fence with three tildes ( ~~~ )
- Creating inline code using a single backtick ( ` )

On the new page there is a short sample section, see screenshot below, on how to format your text using symbols. The bold and italic formatting are used "inline", while the code formatting given as example here is supposed to create a block of code. It would be helpful to distinguish between the two options.

What I also noticed since the introduction of code fences is that people suggest edits in which they put a perfectly formatted piece of code, by ways of indentation, in a code fence. This renders all sorts of useless spaces within the post. It might be helpful to promote only one way of formatting to avoid this kind of confusions.

PS. I really like the collapsible formatting tips, they even showed me some new things.

[image: Screenshot of format help in new ask page on SO]